# Как оптимизировать метод для работы с разными файлами?

Tags: java, ооп, properties

Есть метод для добавления пар ключ - значение в проперти файл словаря, дело в том, что я не знаю как его сделать универсальным, т.е. чтобы можно было использовать один метод на разные словари. Например словарь англо-русский и немецко-английский, при том, что условия к ключу везде будут разные. Не добавлять же отдельный метод для каждого словаря, просто если их будет 1000?

```
public void addToDictionary(String key, String value){
        if (key.matches("[A-z]{4}")){
            propFile.setProperty(key, value);
            try {
                propFile.store(new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(propConsole.getProperty(fileName)), true), null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            map.put(key, value);
            System.out.println(propConsole.getProperty("successful.entry"));
        }
        else
            System.out.println(propConsole.getProperty("error.entry"));
    }
```

Для остальных методов так сделать получилось, вот пример

```
public void delete(String key){
        map.entrySet().removeIf(next -> next.getKey().equals(key));
        propFile.remove(key);
        try {
            propFile.store(new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(propConsole.getProperty(fileName)), true), null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(propConsole.getProperty("remove.entry"));
    }
```

fileName - я инициализирую при загрузке класса

```
 public void startProgram(){
        do {
            System.out.println(properties.getProperty("choice"));
            choice = scanner.nextLine();
            if (choice.equals("1")) {
                dictionary.loadDictionaryFromFile("dictionary.char");
                break;
            }else if (choice.equals("2")) {
                dictionary.loadDictionaryFromFile("dictionary.number");
                break;
            }
        }while (!choice.equals("1") || !choice.equals("2"));
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вам нужно будет менять условие `if (key.matches("[A-z]{4}")){`? Если да, то вам нужно будет менять все условие или только регулярное выражение?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov мне нужно менять регулярное выражение и проперти файл куда я буду это записывать. Т.е. английский словарь - это 1 файл

Comment: проперти-файл это поле `fileName`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Именно так, это путь к нему, сейчас добавлю метод где я их меняю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определите в классе два поля и проинициализируйте их в конструкторе

```
class MyDictionary {
  private final String fileName;
  private final String keyMatch;

  public MyDictionary(String fileName, String keyMatch) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.keyMatch = keyMatch;
  }
```

А дальше просто обращайтесь к ним

```
public void addToDictionary(String key, String value){
  if (key.matches(keyMatch)){
```

Если у вас создание объекта класса и связывание его со словарем разные операции, то добавьте регулярное выражение параметром в метод `loadDictionaryFromFile()`

```
void loadDictionaryFromFile (String fileName, String keyMatch) {
  this.fileName = fileName;
  this.keyMatch = keyMatch;
  ..............
}
```

(тогда нужно будет убрать модификаторы `final` из объявления полей)

Comment: ok, благодарю, я примерно так и думал